# What is the recommended my.cnf settings for 32 GB Server

Tags: mysql, linux, optimization, my.cnf

I am just moving my website to a new server and ı want to know what is the recommended settings for 32 GB server?

Mysql tunning for my old server (16 GB)

https://pastecode.xyz/view/577e824e

Comment: There is no such thing as a recommended config based on server memory size really. It depends on what you want your server to do

Comment: That link shows 58.8GB of RAM, not 16??

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'table%' -- It may be that the table_open_cache was fine.  Anyway, you have plenty of ram with which to increase it.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @H-Burak       We can provide additional suggestions after you post the data requested Mar 24, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # to reduce threads_created count of 16K in 42d per MSTuner
table_open_cache=6000  # from 2500 to reduce opened_tables count
innodb_open_files=6000  # from 2500 to be paired with table_open_cache
```

Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you upped to 32G. It seems from your tuning report that your innodb datasize is 0.5G.

Main thing to look at based on your tuning report is the table_cache. 3% is horrible and is incurring quite a penalty. Aim to get this up to 99%.

Read about table cache here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-cache.html (since you are using MySQL-5.7)

There is a warning about your join buffer size. Start looking through your slow query log (has 1M entries apparently - with what long_query_time?) with the aim to improve your schema indexing and this warning might go away. Ask separate questions about your slow queries. Initial reading - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html